# What am I doing wrong with requests in python: ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm not sure even how to ask the question, as it seems it would require quite a lot of code to get into the details.  Rather than show the code, I will discuss the behavior when I run.

I am using requests to grab information from an online database. When I run a for loop to go through all of my entries, I get an error like the one below on one of the first 20 entries (usually the first, but not always). The entries in the list are all alike (just different ID numbers). I am using sleep() to ensure that I do not go beyond my rate limit (I have tried increasing sleep to ridiculous wait times, but still get the error).  What really surprises me is that it works some, and then gets stuck.... what could cause that?

Also, the code was working before, then I made a large number of edits to other code in the same file, but I didn't think I edited anything related to this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/Riot_API_Challenger_Stats/Main.py", line 233, in <module>
main()
File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/Riot_API_Challenger_Stats/Main.py", line 212, in main
match_histories=get_match_histories(challenger_Ids+master_Ids)
File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/Riot_API_Challenger_Stats/Main.py", line 62, in get_match_histories
match_histories[summoner_Ids[i]]=api.get_match_history_data(summoner_Ids[i])
File "C:\Users\Mark\PycharmProjects\Riot_API_Challenger_Stats\RiotAPI.py", line 52, in get_match_history_data
return self._request(api_url)
File "C:\Users\Mark\PycharmProjects\Riot_API_Challenger_Stats\RiotAPI.py", line 25, in _request
return response.json()
File "C:\Users\Mark\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 819, in json
return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mark\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\Mark\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\Mark\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here are lines 10-25 of RiotAPI

```
def _request(self, api_url, params={}):
    args = {'api_key':self.api_key}
    for key, value in params.items():
        if key not in args:
            args[key] = value
    #requests.get accesses the URL
    response = requests.get(
        Consts.URL['base'].format(
            proxy=self.region,
            region=self.region,
            url=api_url
            ),
        params=args
        )
    print(response.url)
    return response.json()
```

Here is the response:

> {"matches":[{"matchId":1878534497,"region":"NA","platformId":"NA1","matchMode":"CLASSIC","matchType":"MATCHED_GAME","matchCreation":1436223958539,"matchDuration":2097,"queueType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5","mapId":11,"season":"SEASON2015","matchVersion":"5.12.0.348","participants":[{"teamId":200,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":7,"championId":15,"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"UNRANKED","timeline":{"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"zeroToTen":5.699999999999999,"tenToTwenty":6.9,"twentyToThirty":7.1},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"zeroToTen":358.5,"tenToTwenty":350.0,"twentyToThirty":364.20000000000005},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"zeroToTen":365.3,"tenToTwenty":337.5,"twentyToThirty":287.5},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"zeroToTen":-0.7,"tenToTwenty":-1.7000000000000004,"twentyToThirty":1.0999999999999999},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"zeroToTen":-0.9000000000000057,"tenToTwenty":-114.75,"twentyToThirty":-121.19999999999999},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"zeroToTen":480.5,"tenToTwenty":565.3,"twentyToThirty":1258.6},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"zeroToTen":-147.49999999999994,"tenToTwenty":-134.69999999999996,"twentyToThirty":15.0},"role":"DUO_CARRY","lane":"BOTTOM"},"masteries":[{"masteryId":4112,"rank":4},{"masteryId":4114,"rank":1},{"masteryId":4122,"rank":3},{"masteryId":4124,"rank":1},{"masteryId":4132,"rank":1},{"masteryId":4134,"rank":3},{"masteryId":4142,"rank":2},{"masteryId":4144,"rank":1},{"masteryId":4151,"rank":1},{"masteryId":4152,"rank":3},{"masteryId":4162,"rank":1},{"masteryId":4211,"rank":2},{"masteryId":4212,"rank":2},{"masteryId":4221,"rank":1},{"masteryId":4222,"rank":3},{"masteryId":4232,"rank":1}],"stats":{"winner":false,"champLevel":14,"item0":3031,"item1":0,"item2":3142,"item3":3035,"item4":1053,"item5":3250,"item6":3342,"kills":4,"doubleKills":1,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"largestKillingSpree":3,"deaths":12,"assists":5,"totalDamageDealt":184710,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":27477,"totalDamageTaken":30740,"largestCriticalStrike":684,"totalHeal":2952,"minionsKilled":237,"neutralMinionsKilled":1,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":1,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":0,"goldEarned":12074,"goldSpent":12065,"combatPlayerScore":0.....etc.}}]}]}

Comment: Can you add to the error message the character that it's having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful if you can include a snippet of your code to see how you've actually used it.

However, from the exception, I think you're trying to do a

```
return response.json()
```

at line 25 of C:\Users\Mark\PycharmProjects\Riot_API_Challenger_Stats\RiotAPI.py
but the response is not in JSON format.

You can see the raw response with

```
print response.text
```

to see the string version of the response and check that the string is in JSON format.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, as the website says they are all in JSON format, and I believe that the response is in the appropriate format (see newly posted response)

Comment: The very end of the response '"combatPlayerScore":0.....etc.'
is that .....etc. in the actual response?
Without that part, the response you've pasted is a valid json format

Comment: The '...etc' is not in the response; the response is too long to include in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could post the actual code. But if you are unable to do so due to confidential reasons we can surmise some information from the stack trace.

You are using some HTTP protocol (SOAP/ResT) API to get a number( or series of numbers) in JSON format. One of these ID numbers has a character that is not expected or the JSON is invalid itself. Try and print the JSON request you receive before you pass it to see which one fails. Then create a unit test and run it try to analyze it with breakpoints.

Could be some sort of hyphenated or foreign character based on the database.