# Why am I getting this error in Python using the requests and json modules?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I've been trying to process a couple thousand requests in python and then write them to a json file. For some reason whenever I run my code, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 133, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 44, in main
File "E:\Python Programs\API Challenge Aug 2015\API Challenge Files\Execute Requests Files\RiotAPI.py", line 112, in get_match_by_matchid
 return self._request(api_url, region)
File "E:\Python Programs\API Challenge Aug 2015\API Challenge Files\Execute Requests Files\RiotAPI.py", line 58, in _request
 return response.json()
File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 819, in json
 return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
 return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
 raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
builtins.ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Note that the error will occur after what is a seemingly random number of requests. Sometimes it'll happen after under 10 requests, sometimes it'll last for a couple hundred requests before the error occurs. I've exhaustively tried this and it hasn't broken after the same number of requests once.

The files I'm using that cause this error are identical in method to the post you can see here: [What am I doing wrong with requests in python: ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621509/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-requests-in-python-valueerror-expecting-value-line)

I believe my error comes from the same issue you'll find in that thread, but as far as I can tell and answer was never found. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you provide sample data demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Sure, but note each request.get response is about 1800 lines long, here is a gist containing a typical response. All of the other responses are of the same format with varying information. https://gist.github.com/David4Danger/2b89179896ba47eb0a04

Comment: Just to add to my comment, consider this: When I make a request and get that as a response, it'll usually work just fine. If I run the program twice and that request.get response doesn't work the first time, it will without a doubt work the next time and get passed over like it is nothing. It really does seem weird that it wont work one time and be perfectly fine the next time around.

Comment: Are you quite sure that is the data that is actually returned by the request when it fails?  Not just the data that is actually at that URL, but the data that is actually returned on that particular call to try to retrieve it?  It's possible that some kind of server or connection glitch is causing it to return malformed data only on some calls.  It can be difficult to debug, because it may mean that the error is not in your code but somewhere in the transmission pipeline.

Comment: Well, the actual returned data is not as nicely formatted, it is all just one ugly line instead. Here is the same returned data as it is actually seen: https://gist.github.com/David4Danger/61c49c70801aa09ff4b4
I suppose malformed data is entirely possible, could that be why it appears to be "random" in nature as to which request.get's fail? If that is the case, do you have any ideas on what I can do on my end? Possibly skip a returned request if something is wrong with it?

Comment: Hey BrenBarn! Thanks for your help up until this point, I looked into it further and realized I wasn't actually getting that kind of data every time my request was returned - I was actually getting an error for too many requests being made. Now to figure out the rate limits...